# ggarrange disrupts legend key size and creates white space

Tags: r, ggplot2

One of my plot contains legend and the other does not. They are alright when plotted and exported separately. However, merging these two figures using "ggarrange" creates white spaces in the left and legend key size also goes haywire. Here is the code I concocted with "iris" dataset.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
library(showtext)

showtext_auto()  ##It reduces font size to a customization friendly level

setwd("C:/Users/mdnah/Desktop")

A<- iris %>% 
  gather(key="cat", value = "value", -Species) %>% 
  group_by(Species, cat) %>% 
  summarise(mn= mean(value)) %>%
  filter(Species!="setosa") %>% 
  ggplot(aes("", mn, fill=cat))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill")+
  scale_fill_discrete(name=NULL, guide= guide_legend(label.position = "left"))+
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0)+
  facet_wrap(~Species, nrow=1)+
  theme_void()+
  theme(text = element_text(family = "serif", size = 20, lineheight = 0.3),
        legend.box.margin = margin(-20,-10,0,0),
        legend.spacing.x = unit(0.2, "cm"),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.3, "cm"),
        legend.position="left")
print(A)
# ggsave("FigA.jpg", width = 4, height = 2)

B<- iris %>% 
  gather(key="cat", value = "value", -Species) %>% 
  group_by(Species, cat) %>% 
  summarise(mn= mean(value)) %>%
  filter(Species!="setosa") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mn, reorder(cat, mn)))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.7)+
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0))+
  facet_wrap(~Species, nrow = 1)+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.text = element_text(colour = "black", lineheight = 0.3),
        text = element_text(family = "serif", size = 20),
        strip.text = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(1, "cm"),
        axis.title = element_blank())
print(B)
# ggsave("FigB.jpg", width = 4, height = 2.5)

ggarrange(A, B, nrow=2)
ggsave("FigAB.jpg", width = 4, height = 4.5) #widths are equal, so I just added up the heights.
```

Current image

[image]

Desired image:

[image]

list of things I tried

1. Tried separating legend grob using get_legend() but couldn't place them in the desired area.
2. Tried nested ggarrange (Top- legend of plot A + plot A, Bottom- plot B).
3. I discovered small font size does not distort legend keys in ggarrange, thought it was due to "lineheight" but it wasn't.

**My guess is, it is something to do with font size or margin of any element.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would to switch to `patchwork` and wrap your plots inside `wrap_elements`. Additionally I used the `heights` argument of `plot_layout` to reduce the white space above and below the pie chart:

```
library(patchwork)

wrap_elements(A) / wrap_elements(B) + plot_layout(heights = c(1, 1.5))

ggsave("FigAB.jpg", width = 4, height = 4.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @stefan . It solved bulk of my problem. I also fiddled with bottom and top margin of the individual plot using `plot.margin=unit(margin(x,x,x,x), "cm")`